# My first shiny app, posiible formatting error, data appears with first tab but when adding second tab data it doesn't appear?

Tags: r, shiny

I am creating my first shiny app and I have added a navbar. When I run my first code with the corona virus stuff it runs and my data appears but when I try to add my code for my second tab within the navbar, both tabs appear as well as the layouts and inputs but then neither data sets show up so the pages are empty. Any help would be appreciated ! Thanks !

```
ui <-fluidPage(
navbarPage("Navigation bar!",
    tabPanel("Corona Virus Data",
             titlePanel("Spread of Corona Virus and it's effects"),
             sidebarLayout(
               sidebarPanel = sidebarPanel(
                 selectInput(
                   inputId = "continentInput",
                   label = "Continent",
                   choices =
                     unique(new_corona$continent)[1:5] %>%
                     sort()
                 )),
               mainPanel = mainPanel(
                 plotOutput(outputId = "ContiPlot"),
                 br(), br(),
                 tableOutput(outputId = "ContiTable"),
                 tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                             tabPanel("Corona Cases",
                                      plotOutput("coronaPlot"),
                  )
               )
          )
        )),

  tabPanel("Schooling Data",
             titlePanel("How many kids have Internet ?"),
             sidebarLayout(
               sidebarPanel = sidebarPanel(
                 selectInput(
                   inputId = "raceInput",
                   label = "Race",
                   choices =
                     unique(Internet_access_by_race$new_races)[1:5] %>%
                     sort
                 )),

                mainPanel = mainPanel(
                     plotOutput(outputId = "racePlot"),
                     br(), br(),
                     tableOutput(outputId = "raceTable"),
                     tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                                 tabPanel("Race & Education data",
                                          plotOutput("racePlot")

                     )
                  ))
                  )
                )
               )


)

server <-function(input, output){
  filtered_data <- reactive({
    filtered <- new_corona %>%
      filter(continent == input$continentInput)
      
  })
  
  output$ContiPlot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data = filtered_data(), 
           aes(y = cases,
               x = country,
               color = country,
               fill = country
           )) + 
      scale_x_discrete(guide = guide_axis(n.dodge = 5)) +
      ggtitle("Cases By Country") +
      theme_dark()+
      theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
      ylab("Cases") +
      xlab("Country")+
      geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.8, na.rm = TRUE)
    
  })
  
output$ContiTable <- renderTable({
    filtered_data <- new_corona %>%
      filter(continent == input$continentInput)
    
  })
 
filt <-reactive({
    filted_2 <- Internet_access_by_race %>%
      filter(new_races == input$raceInput)
  })

  output$racePlot <-renderPlot({
    gplot(data = filt(),
          aes(x = access_2,
              y = RACE,

              fill = new_races)) +
      scale_x_discrete(guide = guide_axis(n.dodge = 7))  +
      ggtitle("Accessessbility to Education by race") +
      theme_dark()+
      theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
      ylab("Totals") +
      xlab("Access") +
      labs()
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.8, na.rm = TRUE)
  })

output$raceTable <- renderTable({
  filt <-Internet_access_by_race %>%
    filter(new_races == input$raceInput)
    
  })



}  



shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

--------Data------------

dput(head(new_corona))
`346769` = 346769L, `346780` = 346780L, `346961` = 346961L, `347016` = 347016L,
`347028` = 347028L, `347039` = 347039L, `347220` = 347220L, `347275` = 347275L,
`347287` = 347287L, `347298` = 347298L, `347479` = 347479L, `347534` = 347534L,
`347546` = 347546L, `347557` = 347557L, `347738` = 347738L, `347793` = 347793L,
`347805` = 347805L, `347816` = 347816L, `347997` = 347997L, `348052` = 348052L,
`348064` = 348064L, `348075` = 348075L, `348256` = 348256L, `348311` = 348311L,
`348323` = 348323L, `348334` = 348334L, `348515` = 348515L, `348570` = 348570L,
`348582` = 348582L, `348593` = 348593L, `348774` = 348774L, `348829` = 348829L,
`348841` = 348841L, `348852` = 348852L, `349033` = 349033L, `349088` = 349088L,
`349100` = 349100L, `349111` = 349111L, `349292` = 349292L, `349347` = 349347L,
`349359` = 349359L, `349370` = 349370L, `349551` = 349551L, `349606` = 349606L,
`349618` = 349618L, `349629` = 349629L, `349810` = 349810L, `349865` = 349865L,
`349877` = 349877L, `349888` = 349888L, `350069` = 350069L, `350124` = 350124L,
`350136` = 350136L, `350147` = 350147L), class = "omit"), row.names = c(NA,
6L), class = "data.frame")

dput(head(Internet_access_by_race)) structure(list(RACE = c(9622067, 3159471, 1229306, 537123, 187261, 235178), access_2 = c("Always haved device", "Usually have device", "Sometimes have device", "Rarely have device", "Device unavailable", "did not report about devices"), new_races = c("Hispanic_or_latino", "Hispanic_or_latino", "Hispanic_or_latino", "Hispanic_or_latino", "Hispanic_or_latino", "Hispanic_or_latino")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: What is corona virus stuff? The code itself doesn't run so I find it hard to debug. However, I am unsure what happens with the `filtered_data` being created both within renderTable and with a reactive (which also is redundant, you can simply do `renderTable({filtered_data()})` ). The same applies to filt.

Comment: @Auriana It would be helpful if you provided sample data for `new_corona` and `Internet_access_by_race` to make this reproducible. You can use `dput(head(new_corona))` for example, and copy/paste the results in your question/post.

Comment: I apologize, very new to this...I'm not having issues with the new corona portion, that runs fine when its alone. But when I add my second data set "Internet access by race" neither of the data sets appear

Comment: dput(head(Internet_access_by_race))
structure(list(RACE = c(9622067, 3159471, 1229306, 537123, 187261, 
235178), access_2 = c("Always haved  device", "Usually have device", 
"Sometimes have device", "Rarely have device", "Device unavailable", 
"did not report about devices"), new_races = c("Hispanic_or_latino", 
"Hispanic_or_latino", "Hispanic_or_latino", "Hispanic_or_latino", 
"Hispanic_or_latino", "Hispanic_or_latino")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: And for new corona : dput(head(new_corona)) gives `114144` = 114144L, `114156` = 114156L, `114167` = 114167L, `114311` = 114311L, 
`114363` = 114363L, `114418` = 114418L, `114430` = 114430L, `114441` = 114441L, 
`114585` = 114585L, `114637` = 114637L, `114692` = 114692L, `114704` = 114704L, 
`114715` = 114715L, `114859` = 114859L, `114911` = 114911L, `114966` = 114966L...this is just some as its too long to add the whole thing in

Comment: Instead of putting data in the comments, you can edit your original post with the data. You will have more space to use, and easier to deal with.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know Ben ! Should I just add it to the bottom ?

Comment: Sure - you can do that.

Comment: Two things I noticed: (1) you have two `plotOutput` with `racePlot` --- each of these `outputId` has to be unique...try calling one `racePlot1` and the other `racePlot2` (or just remove one if redundant)...and (2) your `output$racePlot` has `gplot` and not `ggplot`